# How to get the Instance from a RecycleView with Viewclass as button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a Keypad App that loads 9 buttons from a `RecycleView` with `Viewclass` set as `Button` in a `RecycleGridLayout`.
The main problem is that I cannot get an instance of the buttons when the buttons is added as a `Viewclass`.  But I can get an instance of a button if I add the buttons as widgets to a normal `GridLayout`.

This is the RecycleView code from which I cannot get the instance of a button:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<myKeyPad>:
    show_input: show_input
    TextInput:
        id: show_input
        hint_text: 'Type number'
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05,'top': 0.98}
        size_hint: [0.9,0.1]
        font_size: self.height / 1.7
    RecycleView:
        id: view_keypad
        viewclass: 'Button'
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.35,'top': 0.86}
        size_hint: [1,1]
        RecycleGridLayout:
            cols: 3
            defualt_size: [None, 20]
            defualt_size_hint: [1, 0.2]

''')
class myKeyPad(FloatLayout):
    show_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        btn = ['7','8','9','4','5','6','1','2','3','*','0','#']
        key_padbtns=[]
        for b in btn:
            if b=='#':
                key_padbtns.append({'text':b, 'on_press':self.process_output})
            else:
                key_padbtns.append({'text':b, 'on_press':self.get_input})
        self.ids.view_keypad.data = key_padbtns
    def get_input(self,instance):
        the_input = (instance.text)
        i_no = self.show_input
        i_no.text = i_no.text + the_input
    def process_output(self):
        the_output = self.show_input.text
        self.show_input.text = ''
        print(the_output)
class theKeyPadApp(App):
    title='Keypad Input'
    def build(self):
        return myKeyPad()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    theKeyPadApp().run()
```

From this code I can get the instance:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<myKeyPad>:
    show_input: show_input
    TextInput:
        id: show_input
        hint_text: 'Type number'
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05,'top': 0.98}
        size_hint: [0.9,0.1]
        font_size: self.height / 1.7
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        id: view_keypad
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05,'top': 0.86}
        size_hint: [0.9,0.5]

''')
class myKeyPad(FloatLayout):
    show_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        btn = ['7','8','9','4','5','6','1','2','3','*','0','#']
        print(btn)
        key_padbtns=[]
        for b in btn:
            if b=='#':
                key_padbtns.append(Button(text=b, on_press=self.process_output))
            else:
                key_padbtns.append(Button(text=b, on_press=self.get_input))

        for k in key_padbtns:
            self.ids.view_keypad.add_widget(k)
    def get_input(self,instance):
        print(instance)
        the_input = (instance.text)
        i_no = self.show_input
        i_no.text = i_no.text + the_input
    def process_output(self):
        the_output = self.show_input.text
        self.show_input.text = ''
        print(the_output)
class theKeyPadApp(App):
    title='Keypad Input'
    def build(self):
        return myKeyPad()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    theKeyPadApp().run()
```

How do I get the button objects' properties i.e. `kivy.uix.button.Button object` from a RecycleView where the Viewclass is 'Button'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

> cannot get an instance of the buttons when the buttons is added as a
>   Viewclass.

## Solution

The solution is as follow.

### kv file

In the kv file, add the following `on_press` event for `Button` class.

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<Button>:
    on_press:
        if self.text == '#': app.root.process_output()
        else: app.root.get_input(self)
```

### Py file

In the Python script, make the following modifications.

#### Snippets - Py file

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    btn = ['7', '8', '9', '4', '5', '6', '1', '2', '3', '*', '0', '#']
    key_padbtns = []
    for b in btn:
        key_padbtns.append({'text': b})
    self.ids.view_keypad.data = key_padbtns
```

Comment: that solved it, thank you very much.  Just one question, why in your code do you have to access the root ```class myKeyPad``` through the App instance?

Comment: Using `app.root.xxx` to access methods or attributes implemented in the root, is faster, easier to read and maintain. Using `self.parent.parent.parent.xxx` is slower, difficult to read and maintain. When the level grows, one has to add at least another `parent`.